# Minimum sampling for maximising the prediction accuracy

Tags: multiarmed-bandit, bayesian-optimization, thompson-sampling

Suppose that I'm training a machine learning model to predict people's age by a picture of their faces. Lets say that I have a dataset of people from 1 year olds to 100 year olds. But I want to choose just 9 (arbitrary) ages out of this 100 age dataset and still the model should be able to predict the age of a given person. My question is how should I choose the optimal 9 (arbitrary) ages out of the 100 age dataset, so the trained model would perform better across most of the ages?

The model will perform better if I train the model with the entire population, so the question is, how to approximate the performance of this model but with the minimum possible sample selection (not the number of observations, but with minimum number of ages.)

I should address the following questions

1. How many no of ages should I select from the entire age spectrum
2. what are the best ages that I should select to train the model

Comment: " I want to choose just 9 ages out of this 100 age dataset " can you help us understand why? Or is this a purely theoretical exercise (nothing wrong with that)?

Comment: 9 is an arbitrary number. The objective is to choose the minimum possible no of samples yet the model should perform well across the whole spectrum. Thankyou for the comment. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes no I get that, I mean why do you want to choose only some of the ages? Indeed, as you say yourself, "The model will perform better if I train the model with the entire population,", and I'll go further and say that optimal subsampling without restriction would pick people of all ages. So what's the motivation for this "discretization"?

Comment: Motivation is choosing the minimum best sample that represents the entire population. Next time when someone wants to train this model, then they can choose people from the required age set.

Comment: what's the advantage of having only some subset of ages in this restricted dataset?

Comment: ps are you treating age as a continuous outcome (i.e. are you using MSE loss?)?

Comment: I see no way of offering a good answer to such a general question, because the answer depends on the statistical characteristics of the faces and on the ML procedure.  If you could provide those details then I suspect you might get some useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a machine learning problem, perhaps you can treat the selection of ages as additional hyperparameters and throw a lot of computing power at the problem.

1. Encode each age as a hyperparameter which is either on or off.  $i$ is an age.  $a_i = 0, 1$
2. predicted age $= f(faces | a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ where the training data available is determined by which $a_i =1$
3. Fit your machine learning model of choice to the subset of the training data with the available ages.
4. Cycle through all combinations of ages on and off (including all subsets) and determine the performance of the algorithm on the validation data. (Cross validate if you have time).
5. Pick the age combination that has the best performance on the validation set.
6. Evaluate the trained model with the final hyperparameter set on the test data.

Since the model with all the ages included will perform the best as you indicated, you will need to "regularize" or penalize your cost function for including additional ages when evaluating performance on the validation set.  This will prevent you from picking all the ages, but will also cause you to have another hyperparameter to tune.

Comment: @noone could you let me know what you were looking for in an answer since you did not award the bounty to this one?